# Backgrid paginator withCredentials

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, pagination, backgrid

I'm using this component https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid-paginator to handle a pageable collection.

I'm using authentication (passport) for all my server calls and for this reason i put `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true}` on my ajax methods.

The problem comes when i use the link of the paginator component

[image]

It does not use withCredentials options and my request is denied.

How can i add the above option to that calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backgrid Paginator has nothing to do with your request. It just provides you a view to handle pagination. What you have to do is to adapt your Collection request. The collection needs to be a backbone.paginator collection ( Backbone.PageableCollection ) which extends Backbone.Collection.

Long story short, the collection that you are going to instantiate needs to have this behavior added by extending the `fetch: function(){}` method and pass the options needed. But since you mentioned that for **all** your sever calls you pass that option, you should use
[jQuery.ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) - even if it's use is not recommended, in your case it applies.

Make sure you call `$.ajaxSetup()` once, preferably before your app loads but jQuery is loaded.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
     xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
     }
  });
```

Comment: I adopted the first suggestion, extending fetch in my Backbone.Pageable.Collection, and it worked. Thanks!